# vim how enter multiple commands at command prompt

Tags: vim, command-line, ex

How should I enter the following as a single string at the command prompt in vim

```
:let v:errmsg = ""  
:silent! /\cend of .*project gutenberg  
:if v:errmsg != ""  
:echo "Not found"  
:endif
```

This does not work, the message is not printed.

```
:let v:errmsg = ""|:silent! /\cend of .*project gutenberg|:if v:errmsg != ""|:echo "Not found"|:endif
```

Comment: What's wrong with the message you get when there's no match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Range-search may be not the best option in your case. You can use

```
if !search('\cend of .*project gutenberg') | echo 'Not found' | endif
```

if you are fine with not updating last search pattern.

Comment: Thank you, this is a simpler solution, and as it also relocates the prompt if it does find it, which is what I really wanted from the search, it serves my purpose better.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the problem is the normal search you are doing. The range search sees the | as part of its arguments and therefore it cannot be used to enter another command. Therefore, wrap it into an :exe call like this:

```
let v:errmsg = ""|exe 'sil! /\cend of .*project gutenberg'|if v:errmsg != ""|echo "Not found"|endif
```

Comment: Where have you seen `normal` here? `/…` search is *range*, it works just like `:1` to go to the first line.

Comment: Thank you, that solves the problem.  I needed this to include in a key mapping, and I find myself continually frustrated by command sequences that will work entered individually at the prompt, but which fail when transferred to vimrc as a string.  But apparently the underlying cause of this problem is the mode that vim is in in each case?